# filter duplications by property name with java stream filter

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

How can I use java streams to filter an object by the same porperty?

The **HashSet** `tasks` contains:

```
task=1, name=hello
task=2, name=hello
```

*(I dont want to use equals/hashcode on "name")*

Now I want to filter the `tasks` producing a new `HashSet` with unique `name`-property.

All objects **having the same** name should be treated as equal:

```
tasks.stream.filter(???);
```

I can solve that by creating a new list and with 2 for-loops by indexing next element and looking for the `name` if it was already put into the list. However, maybe there is an one liner for such problems? Maybe with `stream.filter()`?

Comment: What would be your output type. Please go through this and update your question with minimum reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @RavindraRanwala the same output type as the origin Set.

Comment: Please state the expected output type in your problem statement clearly, otherwise it is misleading and different people may interpret it in a different manner.

Comment: @Naman yes, is a duplicate. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may first create a map using the task name as the key and the relevant Task as the value. Ignore the duplicate Tasks merely by using a `mergeFunction`. Then get all the distinct tasks as a `Set` view.

```
Set<Task> distinctTasks = tasks.stream().collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
    Collectors.toMap(Task::getName, Function.identity(), 
        (a, b) -> a), m -> new HashSet<>(m.values())));
```

Answer (score 0):

I find one solutions:

```
List<Task> tasksDistinct = tasks.stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Task::getName))
                    .values()
                    .stream()
                    .flatMap(m -> m.stream())
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Are there any better solutions?

Comment: where and what are you `filter`ing?

Comment: It is a indirect filtering by "Task::getName" and knowing that map key is unique. Do you know a solution with explicit `stream.filter()`?

Comment: But if you don't use that `Map` anymore, what are you achieving by `groupingBy`? You eventually have a list of all `Task`s, ordered possibly by the keys(`name`) iterated for the map.

Comment: `groupingBy` constructs the map with unique key. The origin task is a HashSet with duplicate names..

Comment: Yes, `groupingBy` constructs the map with unique keys and *lists of all elements* as values. Your subsequent operation joins all of them back to a list containing all elements. You could avoid this by replacing `.flatMap(m -> m.stream())` with `.map(m -> m.get(0))`, to only use the first occurrence for every group, instead of all of them. But that’s less efficient than [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57602947/2711488) which doesn’t keep the other occurrences in the first place.